# What does this sentence in Nick Hornby’s “Fever Pitch” mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions, orthography

> Charlie George is one of the few seventies icons who has so far managed to avoid being deconstructed, possibly because he appears at first glance to be one of the identikit George Best/Rodney Marsh/Stan Bowles long haired, wayward wasters **who were two a new pee twenty years ago**.

Comment: It's *facetiously* riffing off ***two a penny*** (***cheap as chips***, AmE ***dime a dozen***).

Answer (score 2):

> ...who were two a new pee twenty years ago.

Where "two a new pee" is a variation on "two a penny".
(*new pee* is short for *new pence*, which came into being with decimalisation in the UK).

The phrase "[two a penny](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_a_penny)" in this context means "very common".

So the quoted paragraph ends by saying that twenty years ago these sorts of players (Best, et al.) were very commonly found in football.

Comment: God bless the Brits.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much. I never would have put that together. I knew pence could be shortened to “p”, but I didn’t know it could spelt out as “pee”. And I don’t think I’ve heard of “two a penny” before. Not a common saying in Australia at least haha.

Comment: I don't doubt that KillingTime has the meaning. But I'd caution you to think that this is normal. The shortened form of "pence" is "p"; Although it is pronounced "pee" I have never before seen it spelled "pee". It is hard to know without the context but I think this is an overzealous transcriber at work here. Either that, or, if you will forgive that curious, but appropriate, British expression, someone is taking the piss.

Comment: @FraserOrr The book was written in 1992 - "20 years ago" refers to 1972: this was the year of decimalisation of the currency in the UK: hence the reference to "new pee".

Comment: British English "two a penny"; American English "a dime a dozen"

Comment: I'm in the US, but I heard the ditty "hot cross buns; one a penny, two a penny" even though we never saw any actual hot cross buns.

Comment: Used to be common in Australia, but we stopped using pennies in 1966.

Comment: Also, the Latin-derived abbreviation 'd' was used for the old pence (£ s d), but 'p' for new pence, so people started saying 'ten p' instead of 'tenpence' - sometimes jokingly written as 'ten pee'.

Comment: "Two a new pee" is intended as a humorous novel variation on a common expression (that most British readers would know); writers do this all the time - it's an alternative to using a cliche, and is supposed to amuse the reader through the combination of familiar and unexpected. Referring to sums of money as "two pee" rather than "two pence" is something children sometimes do and are chided for by their teachers, in my experience, so there's an element of deliberate childishness (even aside from the allusions to urination). Joke explained ;)